# Mobile container width incorrect vs. desktop

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have taken over a website for a company and when it was handed to me, there was quite a bit of work to get it where it is now.  Some of the stuff in the site, the owners want to keep, some they allow me to change.  One thing I am trying to figure out right now is how to get the mobile version to line up with the desktop version.  It seems like in portrait mode, the container width is too small; there is space to the right and some images overlap.  I have tried the recommendations in other threads that seemed to be asking the same question, but nothing worked so I thought I would post my own question in case I am changing the wrong code.

I added:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

and looked for pretty much any "width" in the css, but to no avail.  What else am I missing?

Here is the site:

http://leisurelandrvcenter.com/

specifically the "Inventory" page:

http://leisurelandrvcenter.com/inventory/

-*Disclaimer*-

This seems to only happen on certain devices and only in portrait mode.  Landscape mode works fine on the devices checked (android only).
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to make it responsive you have to get rid of all the fixed width there are on the css, for example:

if you want to make the inventory page responsive you'll have to edit the following css:

```
#layout-content {
    width: 1285px;
}
```

to this:

```
#layout-content {
    max-width: 1285px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Then in order to resize the images (for example the logo) you'll have to set the following css:

```
img { max-width:100%; width:auto; }
```

Instead of using the `img` tag you should use the css class or ID of the logo or any image you want to make responsive.

Comment: I changed all of the code where you specified and it didn't fix it.  I changed anything that had a "1285px" (which there were only 5 items) to have the "max-width: 1285px; width: auto".  I don't know which other items to change.  Should I change all widths to have "auto" even if they are 600 or something?

As for "img" there are a couple I found:

`.mobile-view .widget-text img {
 height: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
 width: auto;
}`

Is this okay?

Comment: Okay, I got the mobile site working the way we need, but now the desktop version is a little off.  Here's what I did:

I added a class to each of the images, and put their attributes to:

` max-width: 100%;
 width: auto;
`
The mobile site is working perfectly, but now the images on the desktop are off on size.  Some are smaller than others and it makes that page look strange.  Any ideas on what to change here?

Comment: It seems as though the images I have linked are different sizes.  After resizing them they fit a little bit better, but now I can't get them to align.  I was looking at the code for the table and each table is a different size.  I can't find where this size is held since some of the classes "widget widget-script" is not in the css file.  Do you know of a way I can re-size all of the tables so they are the same size?

Answer (score 0):

The images are too large for small screens. You could add mediaqueries to your css that set the width of images to 100% for smaller screens. (And anyway use css to set img sizes, instead of using img attributes in the html)

Comment: Could you give me an example of what I could put in that might help me here?  I know I need "@media", but what after that?

Comment: for example: @media screen and (max-width: 800px) { img { width: 100% } } -  Just be sure you take the size attributes out of the html. You could give images classes for sizes, and use mediaqueries for finetuning